# Python кнопка из tkinter выполняет функцию из command до нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, tkinter, button, python-2.7

Функция `buttons_logic` циклично выполняется раз в 1 секунду, при этом кнопку я не нажимаю, что я делаю не так? Когда я пытаюсь самостоятельно нажать на клавишу, функция так же выполняется

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def buttons_logic():
    print('buttons_logic')

widget_var = Button(root, bg = "green4",\
                    fg = "white", font = "Arial 9 bold", \
                    width = 8, text = 'вкл\выкл',\
                    command = buttons_logic)
widget_var.pack(padx = 1, pady = 1, side = LEFT) 

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести проблему. На клавиатуре (на пробеле или на enter) ничего не лежит случайно?) Или может какой-то скрипт типа того что в предыдущем вашем вопросе запущен?

Comment: Особого смысла в одноврменном использовании ``from Tkinter import *`` и ``import Tkinter as tk`` нет. Либо одно, либо другое.

Comment: @insolor Нет, ничего не лежит) И скрипт никакой кроме описанного выше не запущен.

Comment: @Эникейщик исправил

Comment: проблема не в коде, а в окружении. Ищите что у вас там вызывает функцию или нажимает на кнопку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня установлен python 2.7.15, и виртуальная среда `virtualenv`, скрипт запускал через неё, изначально вылезала ошибка `This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.` исправил ошибку путем добавления переменной `set "TCL_LIBRARY=c:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Python_2.7\tcl\tcl8.5"` в файл `activate.bat`, но это тоже не исправило ситуацию, в итоге помогло вызывать функцию обработки нажатия на кнопку не через аргумент `command`, а через функцию `bind`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()  
def buttons_logic(event):
    print('buttons_logic')

widget_var = Button(root, bg = "green4",\
                    fg = "white", font = "Arial 9 bold", \
                    width = 8, text = 'вкл\выкл')
widget_var.pack(padx = 1, pady = 1, side = LEFT) 
widget_var.bind("<Button-1>", buttons_logic)

root.mainloop()
`
```